# Use divide in java and get a int or multiply it with 3

Tags: java, divide

Got a case here. Trying to solve it, but don't understand how to do so.

The case is:
If the number is divisible by 2, it shall be cut in half - if not, it should be multiplied by 3, and this result will be increased by 1 This will continue until the result is 1

I don't understand how to set this up in java.
I tried with if, else if and else. But I dont know how to get this to work.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `mod` operator (`%`)?

Comment: Please share your if else work!!!

Comment: @Alan No, not very. I am  very newbie to java.

Comment: @RahulTripathi I have not got any work so far. Trying to figur out how to begin this task. Dont understand the case.

Answer (score 3):

This is pseudo code.. follow it and it should work.

```
while num > 1
   if num mod 2 is 0 
      num/=2
   else
      num*=3 
      ++num
```

Comment: Okey. Thank you. I will try to find a way.

Comment: Am I on the right track?: while (numb != 1) {
   if (numb % 2 == 0){
   }else {
    System.out.println(numb * 3 + 1);
   }
  }

Comment: Close.. `while number > 1` Using > 1 is better, in the else block you forget to assign `numb` to `numb*3+1`.. unless you've done that in your original code.

Comment: This work: while (numb > 1){
   utholdenhet++;
   if (numb % 2 == 0){
    numb = numb / 2;
   } else {
    numb = numb * 3 + 1;
   }
  }

Comment: Yep, looks correct. Not sure what utholdenhet is.. I'm guessing number of iterations. But yeah that is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use bitwise operations for the test and division steps, should be faster than numeric division and modulo.

```
while (x != 1) {
  x = (x & 1) != 0 ? x * 3 + 1 : x >> 1;
}
```

Comment: `x & 1` returns an `int`, not a `boolean`

Comment: that doesn't work in Java? figured it would cast appropriately

Comment: in java there are only `true` and `false`, no numbers can be converted to `boolean`. But you what you could do is `(x & 1) != 0`

Comment: changed - been a while since I worked in Java, didn't recall it lacked basic primitive type coercion.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Faster, but maybe more confusing to a newbie?

Comment: @Alan agreed, certainly more confusing.  But it /is/ the way that /I'd/ do it.  I don't expect my answer to be the accepted one, just felt like it should be included for completeness sake.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but a hint:

```
x = (x % 2 == 0) ? (x / 2) : (x * 3 + 1)
```

Comment: that won't compile, i am sure you meant `x = x % 2 == 0 ? x / 2 : x * 3 + 1;`

Comment: Trying to make a java program that divids it in 2. If that works it try to divide the new one in 2. If that not works it have to multiply it with 3 and plus 1.

Comment: Then do like in @LewsTherin answer or sorround that piece of code with a `while` loop

Comment: Exemple: 14 /2 = 7. 7/2 = 3.5 (that wont work) so insted it have to 7*3+1 = 22. 22/2 = 11. 11/2 = 5.5 (that wont work) so insted it have to 11*3+1= 34 etc. until It get 1 as result.

Comment: Yeah, I'm simply not going to write the full code out. The pseudo code should teach you about loops, the modulus operator, pre and post increment operator, control flow. Google them, and have fun! :)

Comment: Yes, same here - lighten up on my 15 second hint guys ;-)